# Como serializar datos de PHP conectando a SQL para mostrar en un select en html (No muestra el valor)

Tags: php, html, sql, mvc

Quisiera que me ayudaran con este codigo que estoy resolviendo para un proyecto de la universidad.

Resulta que tengo 3 Tablas que quiero mostrarla en diferentes select estoy trabajando con el MVC, donde tenemos un controlador general, para dicho controlador usamos la siguiente función:

```
public function registrar(){
    $db=new clasedb();
    $conex=$db->conectar(); // Conectando...

    /*  ---------- Primer Arreglo -----------  */
        $sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios"; 
        $res_user=mysqli_query($conex,$sql);
    $user=array();
    $i=0;
    while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($res_user)) {
        for ($j=0; $j < 7 ; $j++) { 
            $user[$i][$j]=$data[$j];
        } $i++;
    }
    /*  ---------- Primer Arreglo -----------  */

    /*  ---------- Segundo Arreglo -----------  */
        $s_sql="SELECT * FROM lector";
        $res_lect=mysqli_query($conex,$s_sql);
    $lect=array();
    $j=0;
    while ($dato=mysqli_fetch_array($res_lect)) {
        for ($k=0; $k < 3 ; $k++) { 
            $lect[$j][$k]=$dato[$k];
        }
    }
    /*  ---------- Segundo Arreglo -----------  */

    /*  ---------- Tercer Arreglo -----------  */
        $t_sql="SELECT * FROM libros";
        $res_lib=mysqli_query($conex,$s_sql);
    $libro=array();
    $k=0;
    while ($valor=mysqli_fetch_array($res_lib)) {
        for ($l=0; $l < 4 ; $l++) { 
            $libro[$j][$l]=$valor[$l];
        }
    }
    /*  ---------- Tercer Arreglo -----------  */


    header("location: ../Vistas/Entrega/entrega.php?usuario=".serialize($user)."&lector=".serialize($lect)."&libros=".serialize($libro));
}
```

Luego es enviado para este formulario:

```
    <?php
    extract($_REQUEST);
    include ("../../Modelos/clasedb.php");
    $user=unserialize($usuario);
    $lect=unserialize($lector);
    $libro=unserialize($libros);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Formulario</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <a href="../../index.php"> Volver </a>
        <a href="../../Controladores/ControladorEntrega.php?operacion=index">Listar Entrega</a>
        <h1>Registro de Entrega</h1>
        <form action="../../Controladores/ControladorEntrega.php" method="POST" name="form"> 

            <label>Seleccione el Usuario que entrega el Libro</label>
            <select name="id_usuario">
                <?php for ($i=0; $i < count($user); $i++) { ?>
                    <option value="<?=$user[$i][0]?>"> <?=$user[$i][5] ?> </option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <label>Seleccione el Lector que recibe el libro</label>
            <select name="id_lector">
                <?php for ($j=0; $j < count($lect); $j++) { ?>
                    <option value="<?=$lect[$j][0]?>"> <?=$lect[$j][1] ?> </option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <label>Seleccione el libro a entregar</label>
            <select name="id_libro">
                <?php for ($k=0; $k < count($libro); $k++) { ?>
                    <option value="<?=$libro[$k][0]?>"> <?=$libro[$k][3] ?> </option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <br> <br>
            <label>Ingrese la Fecha de entrega </label> <input type="date" name="fecha_entrega"> <br>               
            <input type="hidden" name="operacion" value="guardar">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="guardar">
            <input type="reset" name="limpiar" value="limpiar">
    </body>
</html>
```

En el segundo SELECT solo está mostrando el Ultimo dato, mientras que en el ultimo está totalmente en blanco. Sinceramente solo conozco lo muy basico de los lenguajes, por eso estoy pidiendo ayuda por si algo está mal hecho.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿qué sentido tienen los diferentes bucles limitados a un número `n` de filas en los arreglos de tu código? No es para nada  óptimo traer todos los registros de la base de datos para luego sólo quedarte con unos cuantos. La base de datos tiene comandos para traer `n` cantidad de registros. Es lo que deberías hacer: decirle a la consulta que te traiga exactamente los registros que necesitas. Luego los introduces en las variables que quieras y los usas como quieras. También para eso yo usaría un código más limpio, usando las funciones con que cuenta `mysqli` para tales fines...

Comment: Se que puedo llamarlos con mysqli_num_fields la cantidad de campos, y con mysqli_num_rows la cantidad de registros, pero como es algo limitado, no me interesa saber si son más campos por eso lo deje así :p solo quiero mostrar 1 dato

Comment: No entendí bien tu comentario. Si quieres mostrar un solo dato, puedes poner `LIMIT 1` al final de la consulta (si estás usando MySQL). En cuanto a almacenar los datos, lo mejor sería usar `fetch_assoc`, que te crea un array asociativo de los datos. Esa forma de guardar los datos usando bucles con incrementos internos casi no se usa. A lo sumo, si por algún motivo te interesa mostrar algún número de incremento puedes hacerlo al recibir tu array con los datos. No sé si me entiendes lo que te quiero decir.

Comment: No mucho exactamente como explique al inicio soy muy nuevo en esto de la programación, basicamente no me se bien las sentencias de MySQL, y en dado caso fetch_assoc no entendería muy bien usarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el segundo arreglo sólo muestra uno porque falta incrementar el índice `$j`.

```
/*  ---------- Segundo Arreglo -----------  */
            $s_sql="SELECT * FROM lector";
            $res_lect=mysqli_query($conex,$s_sql);
        $lect=array();
        $j=0;
        while ($dato=mysqli_fetch_array($res_lect)) {
            for ($k=0; $k < 3 ; $k++) { 
                $lect[$j][$k]=$dato[$k];
            } 
            $j++;
        }
        /*  ---------- Segundo Arreglo -----------  */
```

Y en tercero debes inicializar e incrementar el índice `$k`y aplicarlo.

```
/*  ---------- Tercer Arreglo -----------  */
            $t_sql="SELECT * FROM libros";
            $res_lib=mysqli_query($conex,$s_sql);
        $libro=array();
        $k=0; 
        while ($valor=mysqli_fetch_array($res_lib)) {
            for ($l=0; $l < 4 ; $l++) { 
                $libro[$k][$l]=$valor[$l];
            }
            $k++;
        }
        /*  ---------- Tercer Arreglo -----------  */
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracías! que buen ojo jaja, no lo había pillado :D

Comment: No hay de que :). Si consideras que está respondida márcala para que no quede pendiente.